Polar parametrization of hexagon-like shape
I know the polar equation describing an hexagon is
$$r_{\text{hex}}(\theta)=\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}\csc\left[\theta-\dfrac{\pi}{3}\left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{3\theta}{\pi}\right\rfloor-1\right)\right],\qquad\theta\in[0,2\pi]$$
but I can't seem to find a nice or compact expression for this red shape other than using tons of Heaviside/signum functions:

The horitzontal lines start and end at:  $\dfrac{\pi}{5}$, $\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{5}$, $\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{5}$, and at $2\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{5}$ radians, respectively. I plotted these using separate equations of the form
$$r_{\text{hor}}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{5}\right)}{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{5}+\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)}\csc(\theta)$$

Current equation:
$$r(\theta)=\left(1-H\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{5}\right)+H\left(\theta-\pi+\frac{\pi}{5}\right)-H\left(\theta-\pi-\frac{\pi}{5}\right)+H\left(\theta-2\pi+\frac{\pi}{5}\right)\right)r_{\text{hex}}\\
+\left(H\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{5}\right)-H\left(\theta-\pi+\frac{\pi}{5}\right)-H\left(\theta-\pi-\frac{\pi}{5}\right)+H\left(\theta-2\pi+\frac{\pi}{5}\right)\right)|r_{\text{hor}}|$$

"I can't seem to find a nice or compact expression for this red shape other than using tons of Heaviside/signum functions" If this means that you already have an expression using such functions, then please include it in the body of your question. It may serve as a jumping-off point for a more streamlined solution, without everyone having to start from scratch or duplicating your effort.
